# Trying to summarize loan origination by month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, sum

I am trying to summarize monthly loan originations by month from a table that contains loan level data going back to the late 90s. Every month, the most recent loan-level data are added to the table – the month_key field is used to identify the most recent records. I want to group the loan origination dates by month and sum the total loan commitments originated in the individual months. The table attached depicts how I want to summarize the data in my query, and the code below is what I have written thus far - it outputs data summarized by month dating back to the 90s.  Thanks for the help.

**Edit**: JMB's solution worked. Once I added the month_key field back in, and sorted for the latest month on record, and summed the original loan balance I received the output I needed.

```
select SUM(INDIVIDUAL_LOAN_BALANCE) AS MONTHLY_LOAN_ORIGINATIONS, ltrim(TO_CHAR(ORIG_OBGN_DATE,'mm-yyyy'), '0') AS ORIG_MONTH
FROM LOAN_TABLE
WHERE MONTH_KEY = 202002
group by ltrim(TO_CHAR(ORIG_OBGN_DATE,'mm-yyyy'), '0')
HAVING ltrim(TO_CHAR(ORIG_OBGN_DATE,'mm-yyyy'), '0') >= '12-2018'
ORDER BY ltrim(TO_CHAR(ORIG_OBGN_DATE,'mm-yyyy'), '0') DESC
```

Example for how I want the query to depict the data:

[image: Example for how I want the query to depict the data]

How the query currently outputs the data

[image: How the query currently outputs the data]

Comment: I would prefer `TRUNC(ORIG_OBGN_DATE, 'MM')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest leveraging the date datatype to filter, aggregate and sort: this makes things much easier and safer (typically, your `where` clause compares strings, and does not do what you expect). You can handle the formatting in the `select` clause.

```
select 
    sum(individual_loan_balance) as monthly_loan_originations,
    ltrim(to_char(trunc(orig_obgn_date, 'mm'),'mm-yyyy'), '0') as orig_month
from loan_table
where orig_obgn_date >= date'2018-01-01'
group by trunc(orig_obgn_date, 'mm')
order by trunc(orig_obgn_date, 'mm')
```